# Laptop won't turn on after screen replaced

Tags: laptop, display

I just replaced the screen on a HP D60 using [this guide](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/remove-replace-damaged-lcd-screen-hp-g50-g60-g70-notebook/)

I successfully replaced the screen, reattached it, and put the keyboard back on but when I put the battery back in and press the start button the laptop doesn't power on.

I assume I left some connection loose somewhere, possibly the switch board cable - but no matter how many times I try to reconnect it, it's to no avail. The switch board cable is white with a blue tab and a small separate black piece that holds the cable to the motherboard clip (you can see it put together in the above pic).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try it without the battery, but plugged into mains. Does it still not boot?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday after replacing a broken hinge in my HP G60. Each time I tried to restart the computer there was no response.

The switch board cable connection was the problem. The little black clip is an absolute pain to reconnect. In the end, the image in step 8 of this link got me on the right track. 
[Removing motherboard](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/remove-motherboard-from-compaq-presario-cq50-cq60-cq70-laptop/)

I realized that rather than remove the black clip when disconnecting the switch board cable, I should have simply rotated it to a vertical plain. I was able to reconnect it by installing it vertically, then inserting the switch board cable, then rotating it into the horizontal locked position.